# Gulpfile Creating 2 sets of CSS Files

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

My gulpfile is creating 2 sets of css files. Once when a partial is parsed, and another then the main scss file is parsed. I just need one set of files in an sibling folder **'css'**. My source files are :

- assets/gulpfile.js
- assets/scss/_partials-etc.scss
- assets/scss/styles.scss

My intended destination file is :

> assets/css/styles.scss

It is correctly generating that file only when I save the styles.scss file. When I save a partial, it also craps out **assets/scss/css/styles.css**.

Here is my gulpfile :

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

function styles() {
    return (
        gulp
            .src('./scss/styles.scss')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    );
}

function watch(){
    gulp.watch(['scss/**/_*.scss', 'scss/styles.scss'], styles);
}

exports.styles = styles;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

If I change the dest argument to *../css* it generates the file in a sibling folder of assets! and not assets/css.  I honestly cant make sense of it. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** I realized it is generating the file in a child folder when I save a partial. When I save the main file, it creates the css file correctly.  Here is my latest attempt: https://gist.github.com/andymagill/2749eefedbd241380429043d73e9c48b

Comment: try .src('./scss/styles.scss') to .src('./scss/**/*.scss')

Comment: @Damodhar Thanks, but I'm gettin a similar result with that change. Here is my latest attempt :
https://gist.github.com/andymagill/2749eefedbd241380429043d73e9c48b

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown - and I tested it by copy/pasting it.  Something else must be the problem.  How are you importing the partials?  And I had to do `exports.default = gulp.series(watch);` to get it to work - only change.